# What order does os.listdir read files in?

Tags: python, csv

I am using `os.listdir` as part of a script to merge 14 files (each containing one column of data into 1 file)

For testing purposes I made the first row of each file a date starting at 010914

I was expecting it to come out something like:

```
010914,020914,030914,040914... etc.
```

Or in reverse:

```
180914,170914,160914,150914... etc.
```

These seem like the 2 logical read orders.

Currently each file is named `result1`, `result2` all the way up to `result15`

However the output actually reads something like:

```
    010914.000000,120914.000000,150914.000000,160914.000000,170914.000000,180914.000000,020914.000000,030914.000000,040914.000000,050914.000000,080914.000000,090914.000000,100914.000000,110914.000000
```

what is causing python to read the files in this order.

Or is it perhaps the way in which I'm writing the files?

```
for f in files:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(f, '*.csv') and not fnmatch.fnmatch(f, 'TODAY.CSV'):
        rows.append(open(os.path.join('C:\dev\OTQtxt\RAW_OTQ\\', f)).readlines())
    iter = izip_longest(*rows)
    for row in iter:
        f_obj.write(','.join([field.strip() for field in row if field is not None]) + '\n')
```

Comment: Python takes the order the OS gives the filenames in.

Comment: Depending on your filesystem, it may be possible to force the filenames to be in what ever order you like by writing them in the desired order. This works on FAT, and it seems to work on ext3.